# Perform function over many rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with a nvarchar max column that has all kinds of json text stored in it. I was hoping to use something [like this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) to extract the json but that only does one json object at a time. How can I run this on every row and get one big table with all of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look in detail at that article, but it seems to me that you could use [CROSS APPLY](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/04/28/cross-apply-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx) or OUTER APPLY to do that with whatever parsing function you have got.

Comment: And I was thinking dirty thoughts of cursors or delimiters before reading this answer.